# Return only files with Get-childitem in powershell 2

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I know that we can use the parameter -File in Powershell V3.0 but how can we get only files with the Get-childitem cmdlet in Powershell V2 ?

Comment: The dupe covers more but the answer to your specific question is still there.

Comment: @Matt The simpliest `Get-ChildItem -File` not mentioned in _alleged_ duplicate.

Comment: @JosefZ Why would it be? This question is about PowerShell 2.0 where the `-File` switch does not exist. I did find another one that included such an answer but the one I picked appears more related up front and has less "other" information.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to check the `PSIsContainer` property:

```
Get-ChildItem  | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: Okay I'll try it, but does it work for not named files too?

Comment: what do you mean with not named files?

Comment: I mean files without extension

Comment: Yes, it will also include files without extensions.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use brackets in v2.

Comment: Oh, thanks Matt, I updated my answer.